# How to use headphones with mic on a computer that has separate inputs

Tags: windows, drivers, microphone

I have Bose Q15 headphones that have a microphone. When I plug them in my iPhone or in my Macbook the mic works fine.

My PC has separate inputs for audio and mic. I purchased a [Startech MUYHSFmm mm 3.5 mm 4 Pin to 2X3 Pin 3.5 mm Headset Splitter](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0058DOWH6/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) thinking it would make it work but it does not.

I get sound but I can't get the mic to work. When I try to setup the microphone using Windows's "Setup a microphone", it does not work.

The driver is ASUS Realtek Audio HD. I was able to tell the Realtek software that the device I plugged in the mic input is a mic. But I can't get it to work.

Did I buy the right thing? Is it a software issue?

Note that I have successfully used USB microphones on this PC but I never tried to use the 3.5mm jacks before.

[image]

Comment: The microphone jack takes a 2-conductor (aka mono) plug.  The splitter you have has two 3-conductor (aka stereo) plugs.  You could try a `3.5mm stereo jack to 3.5mm mono plug adaptor`, but no guarantee that it will work.  If you can solder, then cut off the mic stereo plug and replace with a mono plug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled ASUS Realtek Audio HD completely and let Windows handle all audio stuff. It works like a charm. So the [Startech MUYHSFmm mm 3.5 mm 4 Pin to 2X3 Pin 3.5 mm Headset Splitter](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0058DOWH6/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that I bought was the right thing...